# Which React hook executes first useEffect or useLayoutEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component and I want to do some calculations right before rendering HTML on the screen. Since both `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` can handle this task, my question is having both of them in code, which of them will be triggered first, `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`?

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://reacttraining.com/blog/useEffect-is-not-the-new-componentDidMount/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is again your own way of coding however, here is small info and you can always look into something more.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do side effects
   return () => /* cleanup */
 }, [dependency, array]);

 useLayoutEffect(() => {
  // do side effects
 return () => /* cleanup */
 }, [dependency, array]);
```

> `useEffect` runs asynchronously and after a render is painted to the screen.

here are the few things on `useEffect`

1. You cause a render somehow (change state, or the parent re-renders)
2. React renders your component (calls it)
3. The screen is visually updated
4. **THEN** useEffect runs.

and

> `useLayoutEffect`, on the other hand, runs synchronously after a render but before the screen is updated

1. You cause a render somehow (change state, or the parent re-renders)
2. React renders your component (calls it)
3. `useLayoutEffect` runs, and React waits for it to finish.
4. The screen is visually updated

So as @**Robert** suggested use `useEffect` most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

UseLayoutEffect is synchronous and it'll block your app. It'll also cause additional render.

I suggest using useEffect and leave useLayoutEffect for some edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect()` runs after the browser paint, `useLayoutEffect()` runs before the paint. So, `useLayoutEffect()` runs first, before `useEffect()`. You can test it yourself by placing `console.log()` in both of the functions and see which one executes first.